# Where does Ubuntu Software Center store its (language) settings?

Tags: software-center, language-support

On a fresh install (13.04) I see a strange mix of languages in Software Center

[image]

The menu (like my system language) is in English, but the descriptions are in German. I want the descriptions in English too.

I am using a german keyboard and have German installed too (for giving support to students with German as system language :-))

In *system settings* I have moved German below English - so it *should* be ignored, I have logged out after that.

I have cleared the "Software Center Cache" with Ubuntu Tweak. The picture remains the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Software Center doesn't store language settings for package information, but pulls them from `apt`. `apt` builds its backend based on the installation language. This has been reported as a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/434601).

If you have removed languages that you no longer need, you can reset the translations that `apt-get` looks for with:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf && sudo apt-get update
```

At least one person at the above-mentioned bug report, says the problem of `apt` showing package descriptions in a language that is now different from the one you are using was fixed by first choosing the language you need in *Language Settings* and then reinstalling the Software Center:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install software-center
```

Comment: The reinstall was needed.

Comment: @guntbert Glad it worked out. I edited my answer to clarify that.

Comment: this custom lubuntu build for my acer c720 had english software names in the software center but spanish descriptions. here's what i did to fix:
1) reset the translations per your first instructions 2) re-set system wide language settings to english 3) reinstall the software center. I believe the person who made the build deleted the extra languages to save space and this messed things up.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the system wide language is still German. May I suggest that you click the *Apply system-wide* button in *Language Support* and reboot.